# redirect multiple nodes on same page in core search results

Tags: 7, search, redirection, path-aliases

I'm using drupal's core search module with pathauto module for URL aliasing. I have one testimonials page where different contents under testimonials category get display in this page. Now, in the search results one of these content get display and lead to `node/35` and  `node/36` in same search result page.

In URL alias I tried to give /testimonials in each content but it gives error that this URL alias is already in use.

I want to redirect this link on the testimonials page (abcd.com/testimonials). Means

```
node/35 -> abcd/testimonials
node/36 -> abcd/testimonials
node/37 -> abcd/testimonials
```

How can I achieve this? Any suggestions or links will be appreciate.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got solution, but still I think this is not right way to achieve this. First enable the [Pathauto](http://drupal.org/project/pathauto) module and make some pattern for particular content type. Then install the [Redirect](http://drupal.org/project/redirect) module. You can find URL Redirects under URL alias option in edit mode of content type.

click on Add URL redirect and add your desire path (in my case path to page /tesimonials). Thats it. It will redirect particular node to your given redirect path.

Hope this will help you...

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Customize the search results page](http://drupal.org/node/175013). Check for available variables.

also [search-results.tpl.php](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!search!search-results.tpl.php/7) to alter the display.

Answer (score 0):

Hi just write a code block in in template preprocessor or hook_init() function

```
if((arg(1) = 'node') && (in_array(arg(2), array(35,36,37)))) {
  drupal_goto('abcd/testimonials');
}
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: a `hook_init` just for this ???

Comment: yes we can use in hook_init()